# String array with repeating characters python

Tags: python

I'm trying to break a sentence to characters such as: "the boy was good", and then get the place in the sentence of each letter, but each time i get to letter 'o', the place stays the same for both of the letters. How can I separate those two same letters?

```
with open("d:\Users\hazembazem\Desktop\python random\crap\encrypt.txt", "rb") as f:
    file= f.read()
    print file
    file= list(file)
    for item in file:
        a=file.index(item)
    print (a)
```

the file is just a txt file with containing: "the boy was good".

a is meant to be the place of the character, but it's instead shows me this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
3
8
9
10
3
12
5
5
15
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: How do we fix something if we can't see it?

Comment: It's because the `str.find(substring)` method returns the left-most index of the occurences of substring. - Just for clarification if you still don't know why does it happend.

Comment: Honestly, I'm confused what you actually do want as output. `range(len(string))` will get you "the place of each letter"

Comment: As a head-start `enumerate(your_string)` will give you the tuple of each character mapped to the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `string.index(s, sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Like `find()` but raise `ValueError` when the substring is not found.

---

> `string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return the lowest index in `s` where the substring `sub` is found...

---

So, yeah, that isn't what you want.

Check this out

```
with open("filename") as f:
    string = f.read()
    print range(len(string))
    for i,c in enumerate(string):
        print i,c
```

---

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
0 t
1 h
2 e
3  
4 b
5 o
6 y
7  
8 w
9 a
10 s
11  
12 g
13 o
14 o
15 d
```

Answer (score 0):

[`str.index`/`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) only returns the left-most index.  You need to pass the index of where you want to start the search for the letter after you find each one.  Something like this:

```
>>> found = -1
>>> for i in xrange(x.count('o')):
>>>     found = x.index('o', found+1)
>>>     print 'Found "o" at index: {}'.format(found)

Found "o" at index: 5
Found "o" at index: 13
Found "o" at index: 14
```

Answer (score 0):

If you loop over the text with an indexed for loop, you can simply use the index to print both the character and it's position

```
text = list(file)
for index in range(0,len(text)):
    print(a[index], index)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a mapping between the characters and their corresponding indexes and store it in the form of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict), you may use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) along with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) as:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

my_string = "the boy was good"
char_mapping = defaultdict(list)

for i, c in enumerate(my_string):
    char_mapping[c].append(i)

# Content of `char_mapping`:
# {'a': [9], 
#  ' ': [3, 7, 11], 
#  'b': [4], 
#  'e': [2], 
#  'd': [15], 
#  'g': [12],
#  'h': [1],
#  'o': [5, 13, 14],
#  's': [10],
#  't': [0],
#  'w': [8],
#  'y': [6]})
```